# In JSX How to redirect on Handlesubmit from DataPicker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am passing the date picked to the `this.state.value` Getting a time stamp of Midnight that day, but I can not seem to get it to render a new page so I can build the booking page. Where it takes the time stamp and checks for available times that day. When I did return the Handlesubmit on a half successful rerender I got a white page and back to the main app page with a blank date to choose again.

I have tried to build this as a functional component in the handleSubmit But also tried to return a component from the handleSubmit.

Here is the last failed to compile attempt and the last successful compile

```
 handleSubmit(event) {
    render(
      {
      const {bookingTime} = this.state.value;
      if (bookingTime) {
        return <Redirect to='/Bookingpage' />;   
        }
      }
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

This fail was from doing something similar to https://github.com/salsita/redux-form-actions/issues/2#issuecomment-318774722

While this is the half successful runs code (Just a White Blank page for about 1s)

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    return <h1>{this.state.value}</h1>;
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

This is the last Successful run on StackBlitz
Check the components folder for and tool bar for files directly related to problem
https://react-dnudvg.stackblitz.io/
Please note the code is there but its not building the app.

I expected for this run render a new page with one `<h1>{this.state.value}</h1>` as defined by the date picker

Comment: Are you using react router?

Comment: No could you include an example in stack blitz so I can be more clear on the correct way to do this. I have been a bit confused on the router. As I keep running into old info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue here is mixing up logic that should be rendered with logic that can go in an event handler method. In your first example, `render` is not a valid method that can be called from within `handleSubmit`, and in your second example, `handleSubmit` should not return components to be rendered.

You can get at your desired functionality by creating a state variable that indicates whether the user has submitted yet. Then you can check that variable when rendering (note that rendering is the `return` part of a functional component or the `render` method of a stateful component.

For example:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: null, // for the date picker
            wasSubmitted: false,
        }
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({wasSubmitted: true});
    }

    render() {
        const { value, wasSubmitted } = this.state;

        if (wasSubmitted) {
            return <Redirect to='/Bookingpage' />
        } else {
            return //... your normal component
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay but I get errors when I place this in my datapicker file so where do I place this?

Comment: `./src/components/Toolbar/SearchCard/Datepicker/Datepicker.jsx
  Line 42:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

  40 |   }
  41 |   state = {};
> 42 |   render() {
     |            ^
  43 |     return (
  44 |       <>
  45 |         <FormGroup>`

Comment: I see how this would be right but it doesnt work for me in my code. So I will mark this answered.