# How to render method from handle submit of a stateful component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to redirect a page on datepicker submit, the problem is I get Unexpected token expected ";"

I have tried suggestions from users and React Docs as well as Datepicker Docs This is where I am now coming from [In JSX How to redirect on Handlesubmit from DataPicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56381473/in-jsx-how-to-redirect-on-handlesubmit-from-datapicker/56381959#56381959) But when applied to my code I get the error

```
./src/components/Toolbar/SearchCard/Datepicker/Datepicker.jsx
  Line 42:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

  40 |   }
  41 |   state = {};
> 42 |   render() {
     |            ^
  43 |     return (
  44 |       <>
  45 |         <FormGroup>
```

Here is the whole file

```
import React from "react";
import "./Datepicker.css";
import "./Btnsearch/Btnsearch";
// react plugin used to create datetimepicker
import ReactDatetime from "react-datetime";

// reactstrap components
import {
  FormGroup,
  InputGroupAddon,
  InputGroupText,
  InputGroup,
  Col,
  Row
} from "reactstrap";
import Btnsearch from "./Btnsearch/Btnsearch";
class Datepicker extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({wasSubmitted: true});
}

render() {
    const { value, wasSubmitted } = this.state;

    if (wasSubmitted) {
        return <Redirect to='/Bookingpage' />
    } else {
        return //... your normal component
    }
}
  }
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <FormGroup>
          <InputGroup className="input-group-alternative">
            <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
              <InputGroupText
              >
                <i className="ni ni-calendar-grid-58" />
              </InputGroupText>
            </InputGroupAddon>
            <ReactDatetime
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            inputProps={{
              placeholder: "Date Picker Here"
            }}
            timeFormat={false}
            />
          </InputGroup>
        </FormGroup>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Btnsearch  type="submit" value={this.state.value}/>
        </form>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Datepicker;
```

I expect the app to render the hanndleSubmit and redirect to a new page

Comment: what is this for? `state = {};` remove this line.. its not supposed to be there

Comment: I wasn't so sure myself, I will remove it and see if it effects anything didnt help removing it, I thought it was to declare the state to be able to pass the variable to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception is because your parser / bundler cannot handle inline properties on the class.

You could try and set that up, however because you are defining `state` in the constructor, line 41 (`state = {};`) is not needed.

aka state is assigned to the class instance here

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    value: ""
  };
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

In addition to that, this looks like an issue with copy pasting code
You have two render methods in this class with unmatching curly brackets. as you can see here

```
render() {
    const { value, wasSubmitted } = this.state;

    if (wasSubmitted) {
        return <Redirect to='/Bookingpage' />
    } else {
        return //... your normal component
    }
}
  }
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
```

This should work

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import "./Datepicker.css";
import "./Btnsearch/Btnsearch";
// react plugin used to create datetimepicker
import ReactDatetime from "react-datetime";

// reactstrap components
import {
  FormGroup,
  InputGroupAddon,
  InputGroupText,
  InputGroup,
  Col,
  Row
} from "reactstrap";
import Btnsearch from "./Btnsearch/Btnsearch";
class Datepicker extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ""
    };
    // this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({wasSubmitted: true});
}

render() {
    const { value, wasSubmitted } = this.state;

    if (wasSubmitted) {
        return <Redirect to='/Bookingpage' />
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <FormGroup>
            <InputGroup className="input-group-alternative">
              <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                <InputGroupText
                >
                  <i className="ni ni-calendar-grid-58" />
                </InputGroupText>
              </InputGroupAddon>
              <ReactDatetime
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              inputProps={{
                placeholder: "Date Picker Here"
              }}
              timeFormat={false}
              />
            </InputGroup>
          </FormGroup>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Btnsearch  type="submit" value={this.state.value}/>
          </form>
        </>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Datepicker;
```

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to include what will make this work. As a whole file, So I can run it and better conceptualize it please I can not under stand what to fix when all the answers are in vage bits for contribution points faster. Not that you are fishing for points. Just so many vage answers

Comment: @DeployedDDOS Not sure what is vague about this. Your code is raising an exception. That exception is at that particular line, where you define a property on the class inline. Meaning your bundler doesn't handle that syntax. So don't assign properties on the class that way. I don't know what you are using to build your code, how should I explain how to make that work then?

Comment: I dont think you are actually addressing the problem that is asked here tho Focusing on something that has been running in version before this

Comment: What? how is it not the problem? you have a semicolon at the end of a **property** on your class. The exception being thrown is around that semicolon... `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"`

Comment: I removed it and now I get `
./src/components/Toolbar/SearchCard/Datepicker/Datepicker.jsx
  Line 41:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

  39 | }
  40 |   }
> 41 |   render() {
     |            ^
  42 |     return (
  43 |       <>
  44 |         <FormGroup>
`

Comment: Also, why do you have two `render` functions defined?

Comment: Okay thank you this was a much better answer, A full answer. I am checking now before I mark it completed

Comment: im not "fishing for points", and its insulting you would just throw out accusations like that. I'm finding issues with your code and reporting it to you. And I also gave a "complete solution" with the whole file fix. If you want to try that and let me know if you still have syntax issues great. if not no worries, I'd rather help people that are appreciative of help.

Comment: one last thing now it says `Failed to compile.

./src/components/Toolbar/SearchCard/Datepicker/Datepicker.jsx
  Line 35:  'Redirect' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

`

Comment: Sounds like you need to `import` Redirect... im guessing react router dom? `import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'`

Comment: You need to be able to read these errors and understand them. instead of just asking for a "complete solution" you should read the exception and try to understand it. `'Redirect' is not defined` means you need to define / import it. Tryna help u here if you can see that.

Comment: And I apologize I am very appreciative tbh. I really don't want it too seem like I am not. I am just sick of stackoverflow elites answering one part of a bigger question and expecting a noobie to get it. And Now I have more problems it did get to a phase for whats its work but now `TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
`

Comment: its not how my brain works, If i have to be very specific on asking a question when you answer its the right thing to do completely answer it. The problem I am facing is there is a shortage of docs for this particular issue. I  need to see the whole thing to Understand the actually code. I am not being needy I have learning disabilities and this is the best way for me to understand is see the clear picture in its whole.

Comment: Ok, so I'll help u find it on your own. Where is `.bind` called? Look at what it's being called on and then look at which of those things are not defined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194192/discussion-between-deployed-ddos-and-john-ruddell).